# While executing the program, getting ValueError: math domain error

Tags: iot, esp32, micropython

I am using a micropython library for collecting the data from the sensor MQ135.

The micropython  code for the library is as below:

```
import math
import time
import machine
from machine import ADC

class MQ135(object):
    """ Class for dealing with MQ13 Gas Sensors """
    # The load resistance on the board
    RLOAD = 10.0
    # Calibration resistance at atmospheric CO2 level
    RZERO = 76.63
    # Parameters for calculating ppm of CO2 from sensor resistance
    PARA = 116.6020682
    PARB = 2.769034857

    # Parameters to model temperature and humidity dependence
    CORA = 0.00035
    CORB = 0.02718
    CORC = 1.39538
    CORD = 0.0018
    CORE = -0.003333333
    CORF = -0.001923077
    CORG = 1.130128205

    # Atmospheric CO2 level for calibration purposes
    ATMOCO2 = 397.13


    def __init__(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin

    def get_correction_factor(self, temperature, humidity):
        """Calculates the correction factor for ambient air temperature and relative humidity
        Based on the linearization of the temperature dependency curve
        under and above 20 degrees Celsius, asuming a linear dependency on humidity,
        provided by Balk77 https://github.com/GeorgK/MQ135/pull/6/files
        """

        if temperature < 20:
            return self.CORA * temperature * temperature - self.CORB * temperature + self.CORC - (humidity - 33.) * self.CORD

        return self.CORE * temperature + self.CORF * humidity + self.CORG

    def get_resistance(self):
        """Returns the resistance of the sensor in kOhms // -1 if not value got in pin"""
        adc = machine.ADC(machine.Pin(self.pin)) # adc = ADC(self.pin) 
        value = adc.read()
        if value == 0:
            return -1

        return (1023./value - 1.) * self.RLOAD

    def get_corrected_resistance(self, temperature, humidity):
        """Gets the resistance of the sensor corrected for temperature/humidity"""
        return self.get_resistance()/ self.get_correction_factor(temperature, humidity)

    def get_ppm(self):
        """Returns the ppm of CO2 sensed (assuming only CO2 in the air)"""
        return self.PARA * math.pow((self.get_resistance()/ self.RZERO), -self.PARB)

    def get_corrected_ppm(self, temperature, humidity):
        """Returns the ppm of CO2 sensed (assuming only CO2 in the air)
        corrected for temperature/humidity"""
        return self.PARA * math.pow((self.get_corrected_resistance(temperature, humidity)/ self.RZERO), -self.PARB)

    def get_rzero(self):
        """Returns the resistance RZero of the sensor (in kOhms) for calibratioin purposes"""
        return self.get_resistance() * math.pow((self.ATMOCO2/self.PARA), (1./self.PARB))

    def get_corrected_rzero(self, temperature, humidity):
        """Returns the resistance RZero of the sensor (in kOhms) for calibration purposes
        corrected for temperature/humidity"""
        return self.get_corrected_resistance(temperature, humidity) * math.pow((self.ATMOCO2/self.PARA), (1./self.PARB))


def mq135lib_example():
    """MQ135 lib example"""
    # setup
    temperature = 21.0
    humidity = 25.0

    mq135 = MQ135(36) # analog PIN 36

    # loop
    while True:
        rzero = mq135.get_rzero()
        corrected_rzero = mq135.get_corrected_rzero(temperature, humidity)
        resistance = mq135.get_resistance()
        ppm = mq135.get_ppm()
        corrected_ppm = mq135.get_corrected_ppm(temperature, humidity)

        print("MQ135 RZero: " + str(rzero) +"\t Corrected RZero: "+ str(corrected_rzero)+
              "\t Resistance: "+ str(resistance) +"\t PPM: "+str(ppm)+
              "\t Corrected PPM: "+str(corrected_ppm)+"ppm")
        time.sleep(0.3)
if __name__ == "__main__":

    mq135lib_example()
```

But when I executr this, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 98, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 89, in mq135lib_example
  File "<stdin>", line 59, in get_ppm
ValueError: math domain error
```

I am not able to figure out what might be causing the problem. I am running this code in an ESp32.
How can this be resolved!
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the values being used in `get_ppm()`? What are they when the error is thrown?

Comment: Did you check the library's [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/rubfi/MQ135/issues/4)?